# How to access data displayed by dangerous html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref, template-strings

I have tables that I am displaying using dangerous HTML in reacting hooks

Live Demo : [live demo code sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/tables-forked-mmgnh)

Data looks like this

```
export const json = [
  {
    template: `
    <div ref={tableRef} className="table">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
    `
  }
];
```

And here am displaying data using dangerousHTML

```
......

export default function App(props) {
  const tableRef = useRef("");
  let tables = data.json;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" />
      <div
        ref={tableRef}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: tables[0].template }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Question: What do I need to do to access table data in this table (assume I would like to change name on input change) ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, **be careful with this approach,** as [it's an easy way to open your users to XSS attacks](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

> In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

That said, in this case you will have to access & manage the dangerously set HTML manually.
Since this is a textbook example of a "side effect" do the management within `useEffect`.

> Data fetching, setting up a subscription, and manually changing the DOM in React components are all examples of side effects. - *https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html*

Assuming you create a state value for the input, `iVal`, you could change the table text like this:

```
  // ... New state:
  const [iVal, setIVal] = React.useState("");

  // ...
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(tableRef);

    if (iVal) {
      tableRef.current
        .getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]
        .getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML = iVal;
    }
  }, [iVal, tableRef]);

  // ... Updated input:
  <input
    type="text"
    value={iVal}
    onChange={(e) => setIVal(e.target.value)}
  />
  // ...
```

So because of the [dependency array](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) (`[iVal, tableRef]`) your `useEffect` will update when `iVal` (or `tableRef`) changes.

Working example forked from your codesandbox:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-access-data-displayed-by-dangerous-html-stocu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: is it possible to use eg getElement by id with useref?

Comment: When used like this you're getting a DOM node, so getElemenyById or any other 'getElement' or 'querySelector' methods should also work. I just used 'TagName' because I didn't want to edit the HTML string.

Comment: i tried like this `let chatta = tableRef.current.getElementById("fname")` but i get error `TypeError: tableRef.current.getElementById is not a function`

Comment: My fault, yes, you should have access to everything listed here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element, which doesn't include `getElementById`. So to get by ID you'd have to use `tableRef.current.querySelector("#name")`

Answer (score 0):

The way you've set it up, you can technically access the table data indirectly by using `tableRef.current`, which will give you a reference to the HTMLDivElement object, but you're almost certainly better off refactoring this code to *not* use dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

Instead, you might want to consider storing the table data as an array of objects like:

```
[{firstName: "Mark", lastName: "Otto"}, {firstName: "Jack", lastName: "Antonoff"}]
```

You can store and update this using the `useState` [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). To loop through and display the data, you'd use a simple map function as [detailed in the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) and output a table row for each element in the array.

[Simple working example here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/tables-forked-nxmkn?file=/src/App.js)